# C string strip whitespace throws a segmentation error (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers, cstring, c-strings

This is the code the linux kernel uses to strip leading and trailing whitespace on a string:

```
char *strstrip(char *s)
{
        size_t size;
        char *end;

        size = strlen(s);

        if (!size)
                return s;

        end = s + size - 1;
        while (end >= s && isspace(*end))
                end--;
        *(end + 1) = '\0';

        while (*s && isspace(*s))
                s++;

        return s;
}
```

Here I use it as such:

```
int main( void ){

    /* strip test*/
    char buffer2[60];
    char* testy2 = buffer2;
    testy2 = "       THING!      ";
    printf("The stripped string: \"%s\"\n",strstrip(testy2));
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles fine but when executed it states:

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
testy2 = "       THING!      ";
```

sets `testy2` to point to a string literal.  This may exist in read-only memory so can't be written to by `strstrip`.

You need to either allocate memory for `testy2`

```
const char* s = "       THING!      ";
testy2 = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
strcpy(testy2, s);
....
free(testy2);
```

or, easier, just initialise `buffer2` with the string you want to manipulate

```
char buffer2[] = "       THING!      ";
printf("The stripped string: \"%s\"\n",strstrip(buffer2
```

Answer (score 3):

During the assignment of `testy2` (`testy2 = "       THING!      ";`), you make it point on static *read-only* memory.

But in your `strstrip()` function you are trying to modify it.

You can solve it by allocating `testy2` dynamically using [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) for example :

```
testy2 = malloc( sizeof( "       THING!      " ) + 1 );
strcpy( testy2, s );

// But don't forget to free the memory at the end !
free( testy2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

A string literal in your code is typically placed by the compiler into a read-only section of your program's memory space.  When you assign `testy2 = "       THING!      ";`, you're setting `testy2` to point to a string literal in static "read-only" memory.  Then when you call `strstrip()` to modify that memory, you get a SIGSEGV, or whatever your platform calls it, at the point that `strstrip()` tries to write the nul char (`'\0'`) because you can't write to memory whose attributes are set to "read-only".  To get a copy of that string literal that you can modify, you could use `strcpy()` to make a copy of it, and call `strstrip()` on that copy.  Of course to make a copy of it, you have to copy it into memory you own, which you could get from `malloc(strlen(testy2)+1)` or `new char[strlen(testy2)+1]`, or as you've done in your original post, by creating a local allocation.

One thing to note is that `strstrip()` both 1) returns a pointer that may be different from the passed-in pointer, and 2) may alter the string at the memory passed to it.  In your example, you're losing the returned pointer because you didn't assign it to anything... which isn't all that bad because you can get the same pointer address back by simply calling `strstrip()` on the original pointer again, but that would be a little inefficient if you needed the stripped string more than once.  But be careful here... if you used `malloc()` or `new` to dynamically allocate space for your copy of the string literal (and assigned the returned address to a pointer, let's say `testy2`), then don't assign the return of strstrip() to that pointer, or else you can't later use the pointer to free the dynamically allocated memory!  When you call `free()` or `delete`, you need to pass it the original pointer you got from `malloc()` or `new`, not the pointer you got back from `strstrip()`.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
testy2 = "       THING!      ";
```

isn't doing what you think it's doing. It's not copying `"       THING!      "` to `buffer2`. It is merely setting the pointer `testy2` to point to a string literal `"       THING!      "`. Then when you call the `strstrip()` function, the function attempts to modify a string literal, which is undefined behavior. Hence the segmentation fault.

You probably want to use `strcpy()` instead of the assignment operator:

```
strcpy (testy2, "       THING!      ");
```